# ¿Se puede hacer un Subreport dentro de otro Subreport en reportviewer?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Actualmente cuando estoy haciendo un subreport le paso los datos de esta forma:

```
  ........
  report.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SubreportProcessingEventHandler);
  .........


void SubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(e.Parameters["id"].Values[0].ToString());
        DataTable dt_subreportCuentaResumen = GetCuentaResumenGrupo(id);
        ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet_DetalleResumenGrupo", dt_subreportCuentaResumen);
        e.DataSources.Add(ds);

    }
```

pero si quisiera crear un subreport, dentro de otro subreport, ¿tendría que hacer algo similar en la funcion SubreportProcessingEventHandler?¿como crearía el subreport de un subreport?

Comment: ¿No puedes usar Crystal Reports?

Comment: No es la idea usar Crystal Reports